# Get Distinguished Name from Active Directory Users GUI

Tags: active-directory

I've been working on a Ruby on Rails application that uses devise and ldap against an AD-server. The server requires an authenticated user in order to list users. I have access to the AD GUI and can use ldapsearch to test queries against it. However, it took me hours to figure out the correct Distinguished Name string for the admin-user used to look up users and the string for the group base in where to look for users.

Example string for service "CN=service_app,OU=Services,OU=Accounts,DC=ad,DC=hello,DC=world,DC=com"

Example string for group base
"CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=hello,DC=world,DC=com"

My question is, is there a quick way to get/translate these strings from the GUI? For instance, I can see that the user "test.user" is in the folder structure ad.hello.world.com > Users, but I can not find the info in "string" format in the GUI. I also see others struggle with this so any tip would be very welcome.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Yes, there is a way to do this through the GUI.  I'll let you know _after_ you complete the 2-minute site [tour].

Comment: _I have gone through it._ =)